# How to convert Arabic text to Hex using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, hex, arabic

Kindly I need to convert the Arabic text to and from Hexadecimal like the following example Using PHP

مرحبا

06450631062D06280627

Regards,

Eco

Comment: Clarification: the input consists of Unicode code numbers as 4-digit hexadecimal numbers, in the example starting with 0645 which stands for U+0645 ARABIC LETTER MEEM. Right?

Comment: yes it is MEEM thanks for your Clarification

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to have the Arabic text written in the HTML document begin generated, I think the simplest way is to convert the sequence to character references, turning e.g. 0645 to `&#x0645;`. This could be done as follows:

```
<?php
$str = '06450631062D06280627';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str)/4; $i++) {
  echo "&#x", substr($str, 4*$i, 4), ";";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jukka, but not that what I want, I recived the text encoded in Hex in the Get HTTP URL, I need to convert it to Arabic Text and save in MYsql, any Ideas please

Comment: @user1160621 Maybe there is something useful in the Multibyte Library: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php?

Answer (score 0):

I get a unicode string with following code.

```
$str = "Some Hexa String";
$replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9abcdef]{4})/", "&#x$1;", $str);
$unicodeString = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
bin2hex($str);       // Bin to Hex
pack("H*", $hexStr); // Hex to Bin
```